# UML submachine state: can it have additional entry and exit actions?

Tags: uml

Assuming one specifies in a UML state machine a submachine state, i.e. `stateX:submachine1`.

Can the submachine state `stateX` then also specify entry and exit actions in addition to `submachine1`, as would be possible for composite states?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A state machine is defined recursively. Each `State` can have a `StateMachine` (see p. 304 chap 14.2.2 of Superstructures 2.5).

So the answer is yes. Since a submachine is a `StateMachine` it can have entry and exit actions (and all other bells and whistles of normal `StateMachines`).

Comment: I am having trouble following your explanation (and to be honest the diagram in the official spec). Are you saying that all `StateMachines` can have entry and exit actions? I only see that `States` can have entry and exit actions. Or are you saying a `Submachine State` can have entry and exit actions?

Comment: Yes, sure. It's a recursive definition. Each state can be a state machine. So it can have its own entry/exit actions. State has a submachineState which is a StateMachine itself.